# Suppose $f(t) = f(-t)$ and $f \in C^\infty$, show that there's a $h(t) \in C^\infty$ with $h(t^2) = f(t)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

So the hint of the exercise is that I should use Taylor's theorem (I'm not assuming $f$ is analytic).

Then it's clear that all odd derivatives of $f$ at $0$ is $0$ so in some sense $h$ can be defined by the Taylor coefficients $h_k = f_{2k}$.

More generally, can I show that if $f \in C^{2k}$ and is even, then there exists $h \in C^k$ with $h(t^2) = f(t)$?

Comment: $\forall x>0\quad h(x):=f(\sqrt x).$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for your response, I think it's clear that that's how you would define $h$, what's not clear to me is why $h \in C^k$ if $f \in C^{2k}$.

Comment: At least on $(0,+\infty),$ since $\sqrt{}$ is smooth, $f\circ\sqrt{}$ has the same regularity as $f.$

Comment: @AnneBauval I agree, but I think the meat of the problem is to show that at $t=0$ %h% retains half the differentiability.

Comment: @copper.hat   For the smooth case or the finite case or both? Because I think it is true for the smooth case, as this is an exercise in the text book "Geometric inverse problem in 2 dimension"

Comment: I removed my comment. You are free to define $h$ however is appropriate for $x<0$. If $f$ was analytic then the answer is immediate.

Comment: Just show that $h^{(k)}(0) = f^{(2k)}(0)$.

Comment: @copper.hat If you are referring to the smooth case, then again it's not clear that the two functions are analytic, if you are referring to the finite case, then how would one handle the remainder?

Comment: @Ecotistician That is were Taylor's theorem comes in, albeit a bit of fussing with detail. I made a mistake in my previous comment. For example, If $f(t) = f(0) + {f^{(2)}(0) \over 2!} t^2+ o(t^2)$ then $h(t) = f(0) + {f^{(2)}(0) \over 2!} t + o(t)$, and so $h'(0) = {f^{(2)}(0) \over 2!}$.

Comment: I take it back, it is not as simple as I wrote. I would need to define $h$ for $t <0$ to finish.

Comment: In terms of showing h (defined for $t \geq 0$ is in C^k, I'm still a bit confused, shouldn't we take the integral term to have decay $o(n^3)$ for $f$? so that it tends to 0 at $t=0$?

Comment: Ok I think I know what you can do in the smooth case, I'm not sure actually if the finite case statement is true:  Using the argument you laid out using taylor's theorem, if we want to conclude $h$ has $k$ derivative that converges at $0$, then by taking sufficiently high order of taylor polynomial for $f$, we can ensure $k$ derivative of the remainder term will still have some power of $x$ left, and hence tends to $0$, so the $kth$ derivative of $h$ would be the same as that in the taylor polynomial.

Comment: You are right to be worried about the Taylor approach. If you take the (in)famous function $$f(x)=\begin{cases} e^{-1/x^2}, & x\ne 0 \\ 0, & x=0\end{cases},$$ then the Taylor series at $0$ is the zero function. Nevertheless, $h$ does exist.

Comment: However, what if we take $|x|$ in place of $x^2$? Is the result still valid?

Comment: This was asked in 2011 on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72497/if-f-is-smooth-and-even-then-there-exists-a-smooth-function-g-such-that-fx

Comment: @KCd Good find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us prove that if $k\ge1$ and $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is even and $2k$ times differentiable (not necessarily $C^{2k}$), then $f(x)=h(x^2)$ for some $C^k$ function $h$ on $[0,+\infty)$ (which can then be extended to a $C^k$ function on $\Bbb R,$ thanks to Borel's lemma). The only problem is the regularity of $h$ at $0.$

For a fixed $k,$ consider the *universal* constants $a_0,\dots,a_k$ (we won't need to calculate them) such that for every $k$ times differentiable function $F:[0,+\infty)\to\Bbb R,$ the function $H:[0,+\infty)\to\Bbb R$ defined by $H(x^2)=F(x)$ satisfies:
$$\forall x>0\quad H^{(k)}(x^2)=\frac1{x^{2k}}\sum_{i=0}^ka_ix^iF^{(i)}(x).$$
If $F$ is moreover $2k$ times differentiable, Taylor gives:
$$\begin{align}H^{(k)}(x^2)&=\frac1{x^{2k}}\left(\sum_{i=0}^ka_ix^i\sum_{j=0}^{2k-i}\frac{F^{(i+j)}(0)}{j!}x^j+o(x^{2k})\right)\\
&=\frac1{x^{2k}}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{2k}c_nF^{(n)}(0)x^n+o(x^{2k})\right)
\end{align}$$
where the (again universal!) constants $c_0,\dots,c_{2k}$ are given by:
$$c_n=\sum_{i\le\min(k,n)}\frac{a_i}{(n-i)!}.$$
Now, since $f$ was assumed to be even, its derivatives of odd order vanish at $0,$ so that for our function $h(t):=f(\sqrt t),$ the previous identity simplifies to
$$\forall x>0\quad h^{(k)}(x^2)=\frac1{x^{2k}}\left(\sum_{m=0}^kc_{2m}f^{(2m)}(0)x^{2m}+o(x^{2k})\right)$$
Assuming (by induction) that we already know that $h$ is $C^{k-1},$ we are done if we prove that
$$\forall m<k\quad c_{2m}=0,$$
because this will entail the existence of $\lim_{0^+}h^{(k)}$ (equal to $c_{2k}f^{(2k)}(0)$), hence the continuous differentiability at $0^+$ of $h^{(k-1)}.$

Here comes the magic of the universality: to prove that $c_{2m}=0,$ simply apply the formula above to some $C^\infty$ function $h$ for which the $2m$-th differential at $0$ of $x\mapsto h(x^2)$ is non-zero (I leave it to you to produce such a function $h$), and use that $\lim_{x\to0}h^{(k)}(x^2)$ exists.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding this proof, what are universal constants (forgive my ignorance). And also I'm not seeing why you can put $H(x^2)$ in that form to begin with.

Comment: @Ecotistician Universal means not depending on the functions you consider. For instance $H(x^2)=F(x)\implies 2xH'(x^2)=F'(x)$ hence if $k=1$ then $a_0=0$ and $a_1=\frac12,$ whatever function  $F$ you chose. As for $H(x^2)=F(x):$ once you chose $F,$ simply define $H$ by $H(t):=F(\sqrt t)$ (for all $t\ge0$).

Comment: I see what you are doing now, this is indeed a marvelous proof which gives the sharpest result. Thank you Anne! Edit: Although, are you sure we didn't need to assume that f is actually in $C^{2k}$ in order to apply taylor's theorem, and to use $lim_{0^+} h^{k}(x^2)$ exists?

Comment: @Ecotistician Thank you for the praises! Yes I am sure: Taylor's theorem $f(x)=f(0)+\dots+\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n+o(x^n)$ only needs $f$ to be $n$ times differentiable at $0,$ $f^{(n)}(x)$ does not even need to exist for $x\ne0.$ And the existence of $\lim_{0^+}h^{(k)}$ is sufficient for $h$ to be $C^k$ at $0^+,$ if $h$ is already known to be $C^{k-1}.$

Comment: May I ask how did you come up with this approach? What were your train of thoughts that lead you to try this? I understand the proof line by line but I'm not seeing what the underlying idea is.

Comment: The case $k=1$ was easy. It pushed me to solve $k=2$ the same way. That was the hard part. After that the general case was clear.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an answer I have came up with using the idea suggested by copper hat in terms of looking at decay of the remainder term. I am not sure if $h(t) =: f(\sqrt t)$ is actually $C^k$ if $f \in C^{2k}$ However, I claim that

Suppose $f$ is even and $f \in C^{3k+1}(\mathbb{R})$, then $h(t)=: f(\sqrt t) \in C^k([0,\infty))$

Proof: Apply Taylor's theorem to $f$ at $0$ to the $2k$ order (assuming $k \geq 1$.

Then $f(t) = \sum_0^{k} a_i t^{2i} +  t^{2k+1}\int_0^1 f^{(2k+1)}(ts)(1-s)^{2k+1} ds$

Then for $t \geq 0$, $h(t) = f(\sqrt t) = \sum_0^k a_i t^i +  t^{\frac{2k+1}{2}}\int_0^1 f^{(2k+1)}(\sqrt{t}s)(1-s)^{2k+1} ds$

Now for any $l \leq k$, if we take $l$th derivative then the remainder term will involve a positive power of $t$ times an integral expression with bounded integrand since we can still take up to $k$ derivative of $f^{(2k+1)}$. This can be seen using chain rule and product rule and differentiation under the integral. (Edit: To elaborate, when differentiating the remainder term, any derivative of the intgrand will decreases the total power of t of the remainder by $\frac{1}{2}$ by chain rule, while differentiating $t^{\frac{2k+1}{2}}$ will decrease that power by $1$, since I'm not differentiating more than $k$ times the total power of $t$ from differentiating the remainder term will be positive, hence tends to 0 as $t$ tends to 0)

So $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+} h^{(l)}(t)$ can be read off from the $l$th term in the polynomial part (the first sum)

QED

It is known that for every sequence there exists a smooth function whose Taylor series coefficients are equal to that sequence, consider the sequence with the first $k$ terms are $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1}{l!}h^{(l)}(t)$, then define $h(t)$ to be equal to the said function above for $t \leq 0$, then this $h$ would have the desired property $h(t^2) = f(t)$ and it is $C^k$.

Remark: I'm not sure if this is the sharpest result, but it is enough to show that if $f \in C^\infty$, then there exists such a $h \in C^\infty$.

Comment: When you differentiate the integral remainder term, you cannot ignore the $\sqrt{t}$ term, which is what I did implicitly in my deleted answer. See @AnneBauval's comment.

Comment: But I haven't ignored the $\sqrt(t)$ term, when you differentiate the integrand with respect to $t$, you get $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}f^{m+1}(\sqrt{t}s)$, which decreases the power of $t$ for the whole remainder term by $\frac{1}{2}$, but since I am not taking more than k derivatives I have "enough" power of t that will go to 0. The need to differentiate the integrand is also why I'm requiring f to be 3k+1 differentiable.

Comment: Correction, there should also be a factor of s from chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that for $t \ge 0$ that we must have $h(t) = f( \sqrt{t})$. Since $f$ is smooth and $t \mapsto \sqrt{t}$ is smooth for $t>0$, we see that $h$ is smooth on $t >0$.

Since $f$ is even, for any $n$, Taylor's theorem gives
$f(t) = \sum_{k=0}^n {f^{(2k)}(0) \over (2k)!} t^{2k} +R_{2n+1}(t)$,
where $R_k(t) = {t^{k+1} \over k!} \int_0^1 f^{(k+1)}(st) (1-s)^k ds$. Hence, for $t>0$ we have
$h(t) = \sum_{k=0}^n {f^{(2k)}(0) \over (2k)!} t^{k} +R_{2n+1}(\sqrt{t})$. (Note that the subscript on $R$ is $2n+1$.)

(Thanks to @AnneBauval's meticulous attention for catching an overreaching conclusion at this point in an earlier version of the proof.)

Let $r(t) = R_{2n+1}(\sqrt{t})$, then
$r(t) = {t^{n+1} \over (2n+1)!} \int_0^1 f^{(2n+2)}(s\sqrt{t}) (1-s)^{2n+1} ds$.

If we show that the one sided derivatives $r^{(k)}(0)$ exist and are zero for $k=0,...,n-1$ then it follows that the same is true for $h^{(k)}(0)$. Since $n$ is arbitrary, if follows that $h^{(k)}(0)$ exists for all $k$.

Let
${\cal T}_p$ be the span of the functions of the form
$t \mapsto t^l \int_0^1 f^{(k+1)}(s\sqrt{t}) (1-s)^{k} s^m ds$, for $k \ge 0, l \ge p, m \ge 0$ (and $t \ge 0$, of course). The elements of ${\cal T}_p$ are continuous for $p \ge 0$.

If $p>0$ and $\phi \in {\cal T}_p$, note that $\phi(0) = 0$.
If $p>1$ and $\phi \in {\cal T}_p$, note that $\phi$ is differentiable (a one sided derivative from the right at $t=0$), $\phi'(0) = 0$ and
$\phi' \in {\cal T}_{p-1}$.

Since $r \in {\cal T}_{n+1}$, it follows that $r(0)=r^{(1)}(0) = \cdots = r^{(n-1)}(0) = 0$ and so $h$ has one sided derivatives at $t=0$ and these are given by $h^{(k)}(0) = k!{f^{(2k)}(0) \over (2k)!}$.

All that remains is to show that $h$ can be extended to a smooth function for $t <0$. The tool for this is [Borel's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%27s_lemma) applied to the sequence $h^{(k)}(0)$. This gives the existence of a smooth function $g$ such that $g^{(k)}(0)= h^{(k)}(0)$.

To finish, let $h(t) = \begin{cases} f(\sqrt{t}, & t>0,\\
g(t),& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Comment: It does not  "follow from this that $h$ has (at least) one sided derivatives at $t=0$". Look at the counterexample at the end of [this paragraph](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9veloppement_limit%C3%A9#D%C3%A9veloppement_limit%C3%A9_et_fonctions_d%C3%A9rivables).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Thank you copper hat, does this proof assume f is at least 2k+2 (or 2k+1) differentaible then ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. $f$ is assumed smooth.